# ValidationSummary shows all errors on one line

Tags: asp.net, validation

here is my code:

```
    <asp:ValidationSummary  ShowSummary="true" ID="ValidationSummary1" ValidationGroup="x" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ValidationGroup="x" ControlToValidate="ddlIso" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"   Display="none"  SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="<br>y is required"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ValidationGroup="x" ControlToValidate="txtIsoAct" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"  Display="none" SetFocusOnError="true"  ErrorMessage="<br>y Base Activity is required"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ValidationGroup="x" ControlToValidate="txtIsoDate" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server"  Display="none" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="<br>y Base Activity Date is required"/>
```

Validation Summarys hows all three messages on one line... how can i get them to show up as bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DisplayMode property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx